# Keep special chars when using deep link with query params with Navigation Jetpack

Tags: android, kotlin, uri, android-bundle, android-jetpack-navigation

I am sending a raw JSON as a String in URI navigation with Navigation library. It looks like this.

```
findNavController().navigate(
                Uri.parse("android-app://androidx.navigation/checkout/${Gson().toJson(orderSummary)}"),
                NavOptions.Builder()
                    .setEnterAnim(R.anim.transition_slide_in_right)
                    .setExitAnim(R.anim.transition_slide_out_left)
                    .setPopExitAnim(R.anim.transition_slide_out_right)
                    .setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.transition_slide_in_left)
                    .build()
            )
        }
```

and then I retrieve it like so

```
            arguments?.getString(key)
```

This works as expected expect for one test case - special chars are not decoded when retrieving the json (specifically % sign)

So when checking the value of this `Uri.parse("android-app://androidx.navigation/checkout/${Gson().toJson(orderSummary)}")`, it looks as expected contains the % sign but when doing             `arguments?.getString(key)` the % sign is replaced with `?` for an unknown char.

**How to keep the special chars when getting the string from the arguments?**

Answer (score 2):

I just fall in same situation, and was thinking about solution for this.
Frankly I don't know if this is the best solution or not, but I've **encoded** my json string, then when receiving it, I've **decode** it first then convert it back to original object.

HYG:

**Encode** deep-link url when sending params like below :

```
val encoded = URLEncoder.encode(Gson().toJson(orderSummary), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())
findNavController().navigate(Uri.parse("android-app://androidx.navigation/checkout/${encoded}}"))
```

Then when receiving your object in the other fragment, you just need to **decode** it first

```
val decoded = URLDecoder.decode(arguments?.getString(key),StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())
Gson().fromJson(decoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()),OrderSummary::class.java)
```

Hope this helping someone facing same issue.

Comment: that is a way but I think this should be handled on the library side

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, I was trying to pass a string navigation argument that contained a '%' character.  Using URLEncoder and URLDecoder had issues for me because the navigation library itself does some decoding so the argument would come back to me already partially decoded and I would get a crash trying to use URLDecoder.

If you look in NavDeepLink.kt in the navigation library you can see in a couple spots they call Uri.decode on the arguments.  So if you encode the strings with Uri.encode before navigating it should work properly.

```
val encoded = Uri.encode(Gson().toJson(orderSummary))
findNavController().navigate(Uri.parse("android-app://androidx.navigation/checkout/${encoded}}"))
```

```
Gson().fromJson(arguments?.getString(key), OrderSummary::class.java)
```